# Error C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function code from site http://h264bitstream.sourceforge.net/

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I ran a h264 parser program downloaded from the site http://h264bitstream.sourceforge.net/

when I run the code i get the following errors

> **error C2668: 'log' : ambiguous call to overloaded function**
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(575): could be 'long double log(long double)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(527): or       'float log(float)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(120): or       'double log(double)'

in the following piece of  code

```
else if( pps->slice_group_map_type == 6 )
        {
            pps->pic_size_in_map_units_minus1 = bs_read_ue(b);
            for( i = 0; i <= pps->pic_size_in_map_units_minus1; i++ )
            {
                **pps->slice_group_id[ i ] = bs_read_u(b, ceil( log2( pps->num_slice_groups_minus1 + 1 ) ) ); // was u(v)**
            }
        }
    }
```

> error C2668: 'log' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(575): could be 'long double log(long double)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(527): or       'float log(float)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(120): or       'double log(double)'
>   1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
>   in the following piece of  code

```
 if( pps->num_slice_groups_minus1 > 0 &&
        pps->slice_group_map_type >= 3 && pps->slice_group_map_type <= 5)
    {
        sh->slice_group_change_cycle = 
            **bs_read_u(b, ceil( log2( pps->pic_size_in_map_units_minus1 +  
                                     pps->slice_group_change_rate_minus1 + 1 ) ) ); // was u(v) // FIXME add 2?**
    }
```

> **error C2668: 'log' : ambiguous call to overloaded function**
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(575): could be 'long double log(long double)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(527): or       'float log(float)'
>   1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(120): or       'double log(double)'
>   1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'

```
bs_write_ue(b, pps->pic_size_in_map_units_minus1);
            for( i = 0; i <= pps->pic_size_in_map_units_minus1; i++ )
            {
                **bs_write_u(b, ceil( log2( pps->num_slice_groups_minus1 + 1 ) ), pps->slice_group_id[ i ] ); // was u(v)**
            }
        }
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: There is no `log` in your code, but a `log2`. Why? A guess is that you pass an integer to `log` and the compiler cannot decide if you want a float or double result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error c2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006544/error-c2668-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function) (from same user)

Comment: the call to `log` is originated from where ?

Comment: I think this is a known thing with VS(idk if it is std behavior or not), if you can just do the explicit cast...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your calls to log2 to look like this:

```
log2( (double)(pps->num_slice_groups_minus1 + 1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 1.0 instead of 1 as Parameter Input. The parameter of your `log(...)` is expecting to be a double, float or long double variable type. Your variable `num_slice_groups_minus1` should be also in double, float or long double, if it's not the case.

Example: `log2( pps->num_slice_groups_minus1 + 1.0 )`